# Find and compare all methods recursively

Tags: python, nlp, similarity

This python code is working correctly and it returns the similarity score of 91%

```
import textdistance

string_a = 'Hello World!'
string_b = 'Hello Word!'

algs = textdistance.algorithms
algs.levenshtein.normalized_similarity(string_a, string_b)
```

But Jaro inkler score is a lot higher at 98% in this use case.

```
algs.jaro_winkler.normalized_similarity(string_a, string_b)
```

How do I find if there is any other method that will return a score of more than 98%?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a method which returns more than `98%`. It is `overlap`

```
import textdistance

string_a = 'Hello World!'
string_b = 'Hello Word!'

textdistance.algorithms.overlap.normalized_similarity(string_a, string_b)

#output
1.0
```

You can check various methods here and check them individually:

```
print([x for x in dir(textdistance) if x.islower() and '__' not in x])

['algorithms', 'arith_ncd', 'bag', 'base', 'bwtrle_ncd', 'bz2_ncd', 'compression_based', 'cosine', 'damerau_levenshtein', 'edit_based', 'editex', 'entropy_ncd', 'find_ngrams', 'gotoh', 'hamming', 'identity', 'jaccard', 'jaro', 'jaro_winkler', 'lcsseq', 'lcsstr', 'length', 'levenshtein', 'libraries', 'lzma_ncd', 'matrix', 'mlipns', 'monge_elkan', 'mra', 'needleman_wunsch', 'overlap', 'phonetic', 'postfix', 'prefix', 'ratcliff_obershelp', 'rle_ncd', 'sequence_based', 'simple', 'smith_waterman', 'sorensen', 'sorensen_dice', 'sqrt_ncd', 'strcmp95', 'tanimoto', 'token_based', 'tversky', 'types', 'utils', 'words_combinations', 'zlib_ncd']
```